# Python Cryptography Multibackend cannot be innitialized

Tags: python, cryptography

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ENCDEC.py", line 96, in decrypt
  File "site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 32, in __init__
  File "site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 35, in def
ault_backend
  File "site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\multibackend.py", line 33, in
 __init__
ValueError: Multibackend cannot be initialized with no backends. If you are seeing this error when trying to use default_backend() please try uninstalling and reinstalling cryptography.
```

So I made this encryption and decryption program, and it's alright. Only problem is it wont build the .exe. I reinstalled, and tried as --onefile.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
import os, sys, getpass, time
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import subprocess
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(795, 603)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 601))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.encrypt = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.encrypt.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("encrypt"))
        self.data = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.encrypt)
        self.data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 450, 791, 31))
        self.data.setAccessibleName(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.data.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.data.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("data"))
        self.encryptButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.encrypt)
        self.encryptButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 492, 791, 61))
        self.encryptButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("encryptButton"))
        self.cryptDisplay = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.encrypt)
        self.cryptDisplay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 420, 371, 20))
        self.cryptDisplay.setReadOnly(True)
        self.cryptDisplay.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cryptDisplay"))
        self.keyDisplay = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.encrypt)
        self.keyDisplay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(422, 420, 361, 20))
        self.keyDisplay.setReadOnly(True)
        self.keyDisplay.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("keyDisplay"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.encrypt, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.Decrypt = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Decrypt.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Decrypt"))
        self.decryptButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.Decrypt)
        self.decryptButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 492, 781, 61))
        self.decryptButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("decryptButton"))
        self.input1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.Decrypt)
        self.input1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 460, 371, 20))
        self.input1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("input1"))
        self.input2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.Decrypt)
        self.input2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 460, 361, 20))
        self.input2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("input2"))
        self.data_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.Decrypt)
        self.data_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 420, 781, 31))
        self.data_2.setAccessibleName(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.data_2.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.data_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.data_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("data_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Decrypt, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.data.setText("MESSAGE")
        self.cryptDisplay.setText("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE")
        self.keyDisplay.setText("DECRYPTION KEY")
        self.input2.setText("DECRYPTION KEY")
        self.input1.setText("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE")
        self.data_2.setText("DECRYPTED MESSAGE")
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.encryptButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Encrypt", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.encrypt), _translate("MainWindow", "Encrypt", None))
        self.decryptButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Decrypt", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Decrypt), _translate("MainWindow", "Decrypt", None))
        self.encryptButton.clicked.connect(self.process_input)
        self.decryptButton.clicked.connect(self.decrypt)
    def process_input(self):
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
        cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(str(self.data.text()))
        print self.data.text()
        print cipher_text
        plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
        self.cryptDisplay.setText(cipher_text)
        self.keyDisplay.setText(str(key))
    def decrypt(self):
        cipher_suite = Fernet(str(self.input2.text()))
        plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(str(self.input1.text()))
        self.data_2.setText(str(plain_text))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried importing the default backend, dunno if I did that correctly though. It took a couple days to make and I would like to be able to share it with people. No idea what to do now, open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this very same problem while freezing the Python scripts. I solved the problem using a patch to the cryptography.hazmat.backends as suggested here 
[github#issues](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2039)

```
    # file: pyenv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py
def _available_backends():
    global _available_backends_list

    if _available_backends_list is None:
        _available_backends_list = [
            ep.resolve()
            for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(
                "cryptography.backends"
            )
        ]

    # patch starts here
    if _available_backends_list is None or len(_available_backends_list) == 0:
        # backend 1
        try:
            from cryptography.hazmat.backends.commoncrypto.backend import backend as be_cc
        except ImportError:
            be_cc = None
        # backend 2
        try:
            from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend as be_ossl
        except ImportError:
            be_ossl = None
        # add any backends of your own

        _available_backends_list = [
            be for be in (be_cc, be_ossl) if be is not None
        ]
    # patch ends here

    return _available_backends_list
```

This method bsically hardcodes the backend modules path to the _available_backends_list. If anything other than the above mentioned modules you are using then you can add your own import to the method.
If that is not solving your problem, try copying the whole cryptography package to the build directory. In my case I had to copy ***distutils*** package as well to the build directory to make it working in the first attempt.

If that worked out, you can try to include the missing module imports to the setup.py